# Full-text search with hyphenated integers

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-14

Compare the following search queries:

```sql
SELECT
    to_tsvector('yellow-green') @@ to_tsquery('yellow & green') as word_word,
    to_tsvector('Apollo-11') @@ to_tsquery('apollo & 11') as word_number;

 word_word | word_number
-----------+-------------
 t         | f
(1 row)
```

They are conceptually similar, but only the first one produces a match. It is quite clear why this happens. With a hyphenated word pair, the parser generates three lexemes:

```sql
 SELECT * FROM ts_debug('yellow-green');

     alias      |         description          |  token  |  dictionaries  | dictionary  |  lexemes
----------------+------------------------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------
 asciihword     | Hyphenated word, all ASCII   | yellow-.| {english_stem} | english_ste.| {yellow-g.
                |                              |.green   |                |.m           |.reen}
 hword_asciipar.| Hyphenated word part, all AS.| yellow  | {english_stem} | english_ste.| {yellow}
.t              |.CII                          |         |                |.m           |
 blank          | Space symbols                | -       | {}             |             |
 hword_asciipar.| Hyphenated word part, all AS.| green   | {english_stem} | english_ste.| {green}
.t              |.CII                          |         |                |.m           |
(4 rows)
```

With a word-number pair, the parser creates two lexemes, one of which is an signed integer:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ts_debug('apollo-11');

   alias   |   description   | token  |  dictionaries  |  dictionary  | lexemes
-----------+-----------------+--------+----------------+--------------+----------
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | apollo | {english_stem} | english_stem | {apollo}
 int       | Signed integer  | -11    | {simple}       | simple       | {-11}
(2 rows)
```

Is it possible to configure `to_tsvector` to parse the numbers like strings, so that the matches would be unaffected by hyphenation?

Comment: This post works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795085/postgres-full-text-search-with-hyphen-and-numerals

Comment: Thank you, I was able to implement `dict_int` without much trouble. I cannot link as a duplicate because it's on SO and not on DBA; if submit an answer I can accept it, otherwise I'll write up my own process in a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the `dict_int` extension, as mentioned by [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66061604/19357965). It was as simple as:

1. Enable the dictionary extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS dict_int;
```

2. Set the `absval` option so that the dictionary will transform numbers to their absolute values.

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY intdict (absval = true);
```

- note that the dictionary will also truncate integers over a certain maximum length, controlled by `maxlen` parameter (default 6)

3. Create a custom text search configuration to use this dictionary:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION en_cusom (COPY = pg_catalog.english);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION en_custom
    ALTER MAPPING FOR int, uint WITH intdict;
```

- One could also directly alter the default configuration to avoid explicit calls in `to_tsvector`/`to_tsquery`.

4. Specify the dictionary to use in searches:

```
SELECT
    to_tsvector('en_custom', 'yellow-green') @@ to_tsquery('en_custom', 'yellow & green') as word_word,
    to_tsvector('en_custom', 'Apollo-11') @@ to_tsquery('en_custom', 'apollo & 11') as word_number;
 word_word | word_number
-----------+-------------
 t         | t
(1 row)
```